# Adding Javascript Game Into HTML Div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm running into problems loading my JS game onto a div, which ultimately should show the game below the header, however it's showing below the footer instead. Anyone know how I can fix this? Thanks in advance. [How It's Supposed to Look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OvvK0.png)

**JS FILE**

```
var animate = window.requestAnimationFrame ||
  window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
  window.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
  function(callback) { window.setTimeout(callback, 1000/60) };

var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
var width = 400;
var height = 600;
canvas.width = width;
canvas.height = height;
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
var topScore = 0;
var bottomScore = 0;
var game1 = document.getElementById("game");

window.onload = function() {
  document.body.appendChild(canvas);
  animate(step);

};

var step = function() {
  update();
  render();
  animate(step);
};

var update = function() {
};

var render = function() {
  context.fillStyle = "#ffd31d";
  context.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
};
```

**HTML FILE**

```
 <div class="game"></div>
 <script src="pong.js"></script>
```

Comment: You are appending to the body with `document.body.appendChild(canvas);`. Append somewhere else. You may want to use `parentElement.insertBefore(canvas, beforeNode);`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
document.body.appendChild(canvas);
```

you need to append it to the div

```
game1.appendChild(canvas);
```

appending it to the body will just add it after everything else on the page.

Comment: Thank you, I see the logic and that makes sense. However, it's still not appearing.

Comment: Do you have a git repo or another way to show me your code?

Comment: https://github.com/tatedewey/WildinOut   Thanks for looking into it.